# how to get duplicated and non duplicated element of arrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, set

I have an object as Riziv with three variables as id, cnk and product. Then I search in a databank for this object and add it to a `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<Riziv>` list.
Now I should checkout if all object in his array are the same `cnk` then return true otherwise I should return all objects which are not the same `cnk` with error message.

```
  public class Riziv{ String id, cnk, product; }
    ArrayList<Riziv> list = getArrayListFromDatabank(id);

    public void getDuplicatedWhichHasTheSameCnk(){

    }
  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want when you say "all object which has not the same cnk"? Specifically, not the same cnk as *what*?

Comment: Peter Lawrey has the best answer, but it is unclear what you want in the situation where there are multiple duplicates, e.g., 4 with cnk=xxx, 4 with cnk=yyy, 4 with cnk=zzz.

Comment: If cnk of all element are the same return true.If not return an arrayList with all element.

Comment: @itro you cannot do that: a Java method can only return one type. Well, you could return an Object, but you'd need to cast it etc, at the risk of getting ClassCastExceptions... Not a good idea.

Comment: then can just return an arrayList with non similar element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standard JVM structures (MultiMap is provided by guava), you can do that:

```
public List<Riviz> getDuplicates(final List<Riviz> l)
{
    final HashMap<String, List<Riviz>> m = new HashMap<String, List<Riviz>>();
    final List<Riviz> ret = new ArrayList<Riviz>();

    String cnk;

    for (final Riviz r: l) {
        cnk = r.getCnk();
        if (!m.contains(cnk))
            m.add(cnk, new ArrayList<Riviz>());
        m.get(cnk).add(r);            
    }

    List<Riviz> tmp;
    for (final Map.Entry<String, List<Riviz>> entry: m.entrySet()) {
        tmp = entry.getValue();
        if (tmp.size() == 1) // no dups
            continue;
        ret.addAll(tmp);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

`ret` will contain the duplicates. You can change that function to return a `Map<String, Riviz>` instead, and filter out entries where the list size is only one. You'll then get a map with the conflicting cnks as keys *and* a list of dups as values.

Comment: I can't change any thing in Riviz class.it is out of my control. Is there any other way to get duplicated and non duplicated in the arrayList?

Comment: I never used Comparator befor. Can you give me a hint or example?

Comment: In fact you don't need it, as demonstrated by my anwser. But if you want to write one, write a class which implements `Comparator<Riviz>`. You'll need to implement the `compare()` method, for instance: `int compare(final Riviz r1, final Riviz r2) { return r1.getCnk().compareTo(r2.getCnk()); }`

Comment: I used your above code to get duplicated with very small correction. `m.entrySet()`
How can i change above code to get non duplicated element?

Comment: Change the logic with `tmp.size()`: if it is 1, then add the entry to the list. (and yes, I keep forgetting the entrySet() part, I rely too much on my IDE...)

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear exactly what you want however I suspect you want something like this.

```
MultiMap<Key, Riziv> multiMap = 
List<Riziv> list = 
for(Riziv r: list)
   multiMap.put(r.getCnk(), r);

for(Key cnk: multiMap.keySet()) {
    Collection<Riziv> sameCnk = multiMap.get(cnk);
    // check size and compare entries
}
```

The multi-map will have the list of Riziv objects for each Cnk.

Comment: Yes indeed.this is what i need for similar and non similar elemet inside arrayList. How can i compare the element's cnk ?

Comment: Pity that MultiMap isn't standard in the JDK ;)

Comment: @itro I have added an example for getting all the elements with the same cnk.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is write a comparator to sort the list by cnk String and then compare each consecutive cnk String to the next, if you find a duplicate, they will be right next to eachother.

1.) Sort the list using a comparator by sorting on the cnk variable.

2.) Compare each element in the list to the next for duplicates.

There's probably many other ways to solve this, this is just the first that came to mind.

I did not test this so you have been forewarned lol:

```
ArrayList<Riziv> rizArray = new ArrayList<Riziv>();
        //Sort the array by the CNK variable.
        Collections.sort(rizArray, new Comparator<Riziv>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Riziv arg0, Riziv arg1) {
                //Return the comparison of the Strings.
                //Use .compareToIgnoreCase if you want to ignore upper/lower case.
                return arg0.getCnk().compareTo(arg1.getCnk());
            }
        });
        //List should be in alphabetical order at this point.
        List<Riziv> duplicates = new ArrayList<Riziv>();
        Riziv rizPrevious = null;
        for(Riziv riz: rizArray){
            if(rizPrevious == null){
                rizPrevious = riz;
                continue;
            }
            if(riz.getCnk().compareTo(rizPrevious.getCnk()) == 0){
                duplicates.add(riz);
            }
            rizPrevious = riz;
        }
```